# Multiple select select all not working on ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a multiple select and when I select "Tous" i want it to select all options but not the first. This code work fine on chrome, firefox and safari but I can't make it work explorer. I need some help here. I tried prop instead of attr, selected, true, false, any combinason possible that came to my mind.

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="departureCity">
<option value="" disabled>Sélectionnez toutes les villes applicables</option>
    <option value="TOUS">Tous</option>
    <option value="1">Any city</option>
    <option value="2">Any city</option>
    <option value="3">Any city</option>
</select>

$('#departureCity option:eq(1)').click(function() {
$('#departureCity option').attr('selected', 'selected');
$('#departureCity option:eq(0)').attr('selected', false);
});
```

Tahnks for your help all

Comment: handle the `change()` event on the `select` element instead of the option. And check for the selected option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work for you:

```
$('#departureCity').change(function () {
    if ($('#departureCity option:eq(1)').is(':selected')) {
        $('#departureCity option').prop('selected', true);
        $('#departureCity option:eq(0)').prop('selected', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. Seems like explorer don't handle .click or onclick in a select